# JMeter : Need to send "Cookie" parameter in request header

Tags: java, cookies, jmeter, http-headers

I am new with JMeter. I am using apache jmeter 5.2 with Java 8. I want to send cookie data in a field name "Cookie" in the request header of a post request at the time of logging in a user to a website. The request header will like the following picture :

[image: Cookie data]

First of all, I am sending a get request to the server and holding cookie data using regular expression extractor and using the value in request header as a parameter named "Cookie". But unfortunately JMeter doesn't add that parameter with the request header. I have also used HTTP Cookie Manager. But I am getting cookie data in **request body**, but not in **request headers**.

I have already seen the following posts.

[How to generate a cookie and send it in a request in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010164/how-to-generate-a-cookie-and-send-it-in-a-request-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

```
CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID",vars.get("jSessionId"),"${serveraddress}",false,0);
manager.add(cookie);
```

Try with the above code in Pre-Processor of the request.

**Edit**: Improve the Format

Comment: I want to send the data " JSESSIONID=24BE2C5D2DA************************* " in a parameter named "Cookie" in the request header. My name of the variable is not 'JSESSIONID', it is 'Cookie'. I have also tried this. Somehow the 'Cookie' parameter can not be sent by the request header.

Comment: You are using Pre-Processor for setting Cookie data or not? If you are sending it with HTTP Request in Java code means the following code will help. postRequest.setHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+ vars.get("jSessionId"))

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the methods on google and not working, I just figured that I can do some tricks on it.

Step 1. Create a header manager and firstly add a header you want. Then in this value column, you just put: "Cookie: your cookie value" immediately after its value. Then save your project. Please refer to my figure below.

[header setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7gkk.png)

Step 2. Open your project (.jml) with text editor and find the content for your header manager. You can find the value for your header in 'stringProp name="Header.value"'. Type a enter before "Cookie: your cookie value" and delete all blanks between the previous value and cookie. Save your .jml with Ctrl +S and reopen your jml with Jmeter and test it.
It should work!

[jml setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCx1X.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVwnB.png)